# Reload modal on confirm function

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a bootstrap modal that contains a table with data, in front of each row there is remove button that when onclick, a confirm alert will show, my problem is when i confirm the removal of the row, my modal refuses to refresh.

here's my function :

```
 function delete_type(id)
      {
            if(confirm('Voulez vous supprimer ce Type ?'))
          {
            // ajax delete data from database
              $.ajax({
                url : "<?php echo site_url('index.php/type_matiere/type_delete')?>/"+id,
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "JSON",
                success: function(data)
                {

                $('#my_modal').location.reload(); 



                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
                {
                    alert('Error deleting data');
                }
            });

          }
      }
```

Help please!
Thank you !

Comment: what do you want to refresh?

Comment: $('#my_modal').location.reload();  only the modal

Comment: i don't think `location reload` works like that

Answer (score 0):

From the structure you are using, you make a GET call not a POST call to your server. You could let your PHP-script return/echo the updated table in HTML. With that you could use something like (I've adjusted the type, dataType and success function):

```
$.ajax({
  url : "<?php echo site_url('index.php/type_matiere/type_delete')?>/"+id,
  type: "GET",
  dataType: "HTML",
  success: function(data)
     {
        /*
          data is the HTML of the updated table, alternativly if you get JSON you 
          could make a function that parses the json and transforms it into HTML

          Please change the dataType back to JSON then.

          var data = my_function_to_parse_json_to_html(data)
        */
        $('#my_modal .modal-body').html(data); 
     }
  });
```